# Lua: attempt to perform arithmetic on global 'mapfinishes' (a nil value)

Tags: lua

I'm trying to set up something in a game that runs off of Lua and this specific local function is triggered when the player finishes the map. Here is the code:

```
local function setDrRanks( ply )
    local name = SQLStr( ply:Nick() )
    local sid = ply:SteamID()

    drsql:query( "SELECT MapFinishes from dr_exp WHERE SteamID = '"..sid.."'", function( q, data )
        local row = data[1]

        if ( row ) then
            mapfinishes = row["Mapfinishes"]
        end

        drsql:query( "REPLACE into dr_exp (`SteamID`, `PlayerName`, `MapFinishes`) VALUES('"..sid.."', "..name..", '"..(mapfinishes+1).."');" );
    end )
end
```

The function is to insert into SQL via a lua function, which it did successfully when ran the first time, as the player was at 0 finishes. Once they hit 1, it refused to do a simple +1 on the mapfinishes value. Which strange is that this seems to work 100% when the player is at 0 finishes, and it will put them at 1, but once they are at 1, it will not add to it any longer. The error received is:

```
attempt to perform arithmetic on global 'mapfinishes' (a nil value)
```

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all: don't make `mapfinishes` global. Nobody knows if something outside your functions changes his value. Furthermore you should check what is returned by `row["Mapfinishes"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    local row = data[1]

    if ( row ) then
        mapfinishes = row["Mapfinishes"]
    end

    drsql:query( "REPLACE into dr_exp (`SteamID`, `PlayerName`, `MapFinishes`) VALUES('"..sid.."', "..name..", '"..(mapfinishes+1).."');" )
```

The issue is in the expression `mapfinishes+1` which seems to have gotten executed without `mapfinishes` getting set. This implies that the `if` loop above didn't execute because `row` was `nil` or `false`. Remember, in Lua, zero and the empty string are truth values.

Another possibility is that the `row["Mapfinishes"]` itself was `nil` so that `mapfinishes` remains `nil`.

Usually it's better to have minimal/no global variables. If you're going to use `mapfinishes` only within this function, it'd be appropriate to declare it `local`.

Comment: Both of you were right about `row["Mapfinishes"]` - The problem was that this was a spelling/capitalization error. It should have been MapFinishes and not the other way around. Whoops. Thanks though.

Comment: I guess the real credit for this goes to @Youka since he spotted it first, I just reiterated it here :)

Comment: @legends2k I wanted to play with him by pushing him step-by-step to this tiny fault and same time correct your answer, but you did so many edits in short time... at the end, you cleared everything ^^"